# workflow for building rails engines as gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

We are looking into building a very large rails application and considering using engines for better separation of "modules" out of the main app.

we have started this process by creating a small engine using the gem motorhead (the idea of its active_if component is wanted).
That engine was then removed from the main app and given a git init, then pushed to github.

the main app then was able to pull the gem in within the Gemfile.

During this proof of concept, it works, but not very efficient, and also updating the new engine/gem is a bit awkward in this way as it is kinda a submodule in a way.   What is the proper workflow for building and maintaining engines/gems when building a modular app like this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can take your engine gems and embed them inside your main Rails app; for example, under `app/engines` or `lib/engines`; and then use your Gemfile to load the gem directly from that relative path (using the `path:` option). This keeps everything in one repository, but logically fully separated, and you have the option to fully extract each engine to a real gem if desired.

Comment: Thanks Robert, and yeah, we have tried both options.  The main question is, IF we want to have them completely separated gems, how best to continue development of them?  i.e. they currently dont have a gemfile etc and cant be started alone via rails server.  Also, when a change is made to the gem (again while developing it), the main app needs restarting or gem spring

Comment: Your comment is the argument for monoliths rather than SOA. DHH's postion: https://m.signalvnoise.com/the-majestic-monolith-29166d022228

Comment: The `combustion` gem is very handy for testing engines in isolation. If you want to fully spin up each engine separately, though, you could use a thin dummy app, contained within each engine's gem somewhere, whose only purpose is to provide just enough functionality for the engine to run.

Comment: thanks @toddmetheny... that was well worth the read.  I am now reconsidering this approach

Answer (score 1):

The most akward part about deploying Gems or Engines as modules is the constant need to update. We had a lot of success with using:

`bundle config local.my_gem ~/projects/my_gem/`

It'll point to the Gem/Engine version on disk without modifying the Gemfile and Gemfile.lock.

To remove the local override run:

`bundle config --delete local.my_gem ~/projects/my_gem/`

With this you should be able to restrict the times the Gemfile.lock has to be updated to deployment time.